# How to get the value of certain applied filter from layered navigation?

Tags: magento-1.7

i need to display value of certain applied filter in layered navigation.

```
  <?php $appliedFilters = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getState()->getFilters();

        foreach ($appliedFilters as $item) {
            $item->getName(); 
            $item->getLabel(); 
            $item->getFilter()->getRequestVar() == 'my_attribute'; // My attribute code
                echo $item->getLabel();

                }
        ?>
```

This code returns all the values ​​of all the selected attributes.

I need to display only value from 'my_attribute'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing an if statement:

```
if ($item->getFilter()->getRequestVar() == 'my_attribute') {
    echo $item->getLabel();
}
```

All you have is

```
$item->getFilter()->getRequestVar() == 'my_attribute';
```